# React Higher Order Component Warning

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, higher-order-components

I am using a HOC in react to restrict access to a component but I get the following Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of . The entire code for the HOC (as requested) is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as selectors from '../../store/selectors';

class AccessRestrictedComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    mode: PropTypes.string.isRequired,

    useWithList: PropTypes.bool,
    checkItem: PropTypes.bool,

    restrictByRole: PropTypes.bool,
    restrictByMode: PropTypes.bool,
    allowedRoles: PropTypes.array,
    allowedModes: PropTypes.array,
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    useWithList: false,
    checkItem: null,
    restrictByRole: false,
    restrictByMode: false,
    allowedRoles: [],
    allowedModes: [],
  };

  render() {
    const { auth, mode, restrictByRole, restrictByMode, allowedRoles, allowedModes, useWithList, checkItem } = this.props;
    const { role } = auth;

    if (useWithList && !checkItem) {
      return  (React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.props }));
    }

    if (restrictByRole && restrictByMode) {
      // console.log('restricting role and mode ');
      if (allowedRoles.includes(role) && allowedModes.includes(mode)) {
        // console.log(`role: ${role} and mode: ${mode} allowed.`);
        return (React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.props }));
      } return null;
    }
    if (restrictByRole) {
      // console.log('restricting role ');
      if (allowedRoles.includes(role)) {
        // console.log(`role: ${role} allowed.`);
        return (React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.props }));
      } return null;
    }
    if (restrictByMode) {
      // console.log('restricting mode ');
      if (allowedModes.includes(mode)) {
        // console.log(`${mode} allowed.`);
        return (React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.props }));
      } return null;
    }
    // console.log('component unrestricted');
    return (React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.props }));
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  state,
  auth: selectors.getAuth(state),
  mode: selectors.getMode(state),
});



export default  connect(mapStateToProps)(AccessRestrictedComponent);
```

the component I am wrapping is a styled component NavButton. I use the HOC like this:

```
<AccessRestrictedComponent restrictByRole allowedRoles={[userRoles.ADMIN]}>
  <NavButton onClick={() => this.setState({ set: true })}>
    <Icon className="material-icons md-48" color={color}>{'wallpaper'}</Icon>
  </NavButton>
</AccessRestrictedComponent>
```

and the styled component is like this:

```
export const NavButton = styled.button`
  display:flex;
  align-content:flex-end;
  align-self:flex-end;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  &:hover,
  &:focus{
    ${Icon}{
      cursor: pointer;
      color: ${props => props.theme.theme === themeTypes.LIGHT ? colors.SLATE_BLUE_50 : colors.lightBlue};
      border-radius: 4px;
      outline: none;
      background: linear-gradient(${colors.shuttleGrey}, ${colors.shuttleGrey}) padding-box,
                  repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,
                    ${colors.submarine} 0, ${colors.submarine} 25%, transparent 0, transparent 50%
                  ) 0 / 8px 8px;
    }
  }
`;
```

I do not understand this warning because I am not nesting a button but when I inspect the UI with dev tools there are two buttons nested. Does anyone know what could be causing this? Is it styled components? the HOC, something else maybe? I guess a simple solution is to change the styled component to something other than a button but I feel this should be valid code. Anyways, any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Johnny, The code shown is just a snippet from the HOC showing the condition for rendering as you pointed out. I can make an edit to show the entire component though.

Comment: no the icon is just an icon. export const Icon = styled.i` color: ${props => props.color};`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because when you clone the element, you pass children to cloned child as props. So your parent clones the `button` and sends another button as props to your cloned button.

Fix is simple, don't send `children` as merged props.

```
render() {
  const { children, ...rest } = this.props;
  // ...rest
  return React.cloneElement(children, { ...rest });

  //...rest
}
```

This way you wont send `children` as props to `children` again.

**Note**: You should replace all your `React.cloneElement()` calls